# ifx and pdflastypos

Tags: pdftex, conditionals

I'm not fully grasping how the `\ifx` command handles types.

How should the following def's read to make the `\ifx` statement true when `pdflastypos` is at the zero coordinate?

```
\def\nothingness{0}
\def\lastypos{\pdflastypos}

\ifx\lastypos\nothingness
  TRUE \newline
\else
  FALSE \newline
\fi
```

Comment: I had to read [@HeikoOberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76353)'s solution to understand why there was a command giving the last typo, and why it was misspelt.

Comment: @LSpice As you've probably noticed, it is the 'LastYPos' or rather the 'Last Y-Position' not 'Last Typo'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `\ifx` will be false for that definition. TeX doesn't really believe in types. `\ifx` just compares the token lists in the definition and the token `0` is not the same as the token `\pdflastypos`

```
\ifnum\pdflastypos=\nothingness\relax
```

would test to true as `\ifnum` expands tokens to find a `<number>`

Answer (score 7):

The explicit question is already answered by David Carlisle. Thus this answer adds a more complete use case. `\pdflastxpos` and `\pdflastypos` cannot be used in a direct way.
Previously `\pdfsavepos` must be called and the positions are availabe at shipout time.
Thus the values `\pdflastxpos` and `\pdflastypos` needs to be written to a auxiliary file.
Then in the next LaTeX run the stored values from the auxiliary file can be used.
Package `zref-savepos` (of project `zref`) provides an interface for the `\pdfsavepos`
feature that remembers the values in references:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}[2010/03/26]
\begin{document}
Somewhere\zsavepos{somewhere}

\zifrefundefined{somewhere}{%
  \typeout{Y-position: unknown}%
}{%
  \ifnum\zposy{somewhere}=0 %
    \typeout{Y-position: zero}%
  \else
    \typeout{Y-position: \zposy{somewhere}sp}%
  \fi
}
\end{document}
```